# MIKE SHE Lateral inflow outputs and the differences between them

Tags: hydrology, groundwater, numerical-modelling, flooding, watershed

There are four 'Lateral inflow' related variables coming out from the .res1d file

1. Lateral inflow SHE overland
2. Lateral inflow SHE saturated zone
3. Lateral inflow SHE overland drain
4. Lateral inflow SHE saturated zone drain

I am trying to get estimate how much water is entering the different watersheds in the model domain that I am working on. However, I don't quite understand the difference between these four variables, especially, the difference between the 'overland' vs 'overland drain' and  'saturated zone' vs 'saturated zone drain'